# What does it mean when a file is owned by the user "root" and the group "root"?

Tags: linux, permissions

Say that we have the following file that is owned by the user `root` and the group `root`:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 54 2017-12-18 04:21 1.txt
```

And say that we have a process with a `fsuid` of `root` but with a `fsgid` of some other group other than `root`.

The user permissions for the file says that the owner user can read it and write to it but not execute it. But I think that since the process have a `fsuid` of `root`, then the user permissions of the file does not apply to the process, and so the process will be able to read and write and execute the file, correct?

Now say that we have a process with a `fsgid` of `root` but with a `fsuid` of some other user other than `root`.

The group permissions for the file says that the owner group can read it but not write to it and execute it. Now I think that in this case the process does not have full access to the file and only the group permissions of the file apply to the process, correct?

Answer (score 9):

The rules are as following:

- If the user is the root-user (UID=0) grant full access
- If the user is the owner, use the owner-triplet as permission
- If the user isn't the owner but belong to the group, use the group-triplet as permission
- It the user is neither the owner nor member of the group, use the other-triplet as permission

So for root it doesn't matter much anyway - but for other users, it's the most specific permission-triplet that applies.  So in your example, if the user is both the owner and a member of the group, it's the owner-triplet that's used (not the group-triplet).  So if the group got both read-and-write-permission, but the owner only got read-permission; then the owner will only be allowed to read the file - even though his group-membership *ought to* let him write to it too.  Other (non-owner) members of the group, will be allowed to both read-and-write the file.

The owner of a file can always add more permission to himself if he needs to - and sometimes a program may do it for you.  For example, if you got a write-protected file (eg. permission r--r-----), some editors will allow you to write to them anyway (usually after a confirmation).  The editor is running as you, and as you own the file and can change its permissions, the editor can remove write-protection and allow you to save the file.

+++

It means that it's the root-user who owns the file and got permission to both read and write it - the owner (root) may also change the file's permission.  And that members of the root-group are allowed to read it.  Other users can neither read, write nor execute the file.  (Since it's a text-file, it's probably little point of executing it anyway.)

Many files on a Linux-system got root-user as it's owner and root-group as it's group.  Although, traditionally various system-users and system-groups - like bin, sys, proc, operator - owned many files rather than root.  For example, the binaries (the executable programs) usually had bin-user and/or bin-group as ownership (eg. bin:bin or root:bin).

The exception to this was executables that had to run as root - they had to be owned by the root-user.  Usually programs execute as/with the permission of whomever user executed the program.  If you run the command `ls`, it runs with your permissions, and therefore cannot show directories you're not allowed to list (like the directories of other users).  If a command is run with root-permission on the other hand, it got access to the whole system (which is why you don't want to that on most executables).

One good is example is the `passwd`-command which lets you change password.  This is run as root, and gives any user *limited access* to the files used to store the user-and password-databases.

rwsr-xr-x root:root /usr/bin/passwd

s=x+S, where x is execute-permission, and S is run as owner or run as group, depending if it's set for the owner or group triplet.

So root-user is the owner; and got read, write and execute permission.  root-group is the group, and got read and execute permission.  While other users also got read and execute permissions.  In addition, the executable will run with the permissions of it's owner - ie. root - and not with the permissions of the user executing it (as is normal), thanks to the "s" (u+s) in the owner-triplet.

Another example, this time from BSD (a UNIX OS):

rws-x--- root:wheel /bin/su

This means the the executable `su` is always run as it's owner - root.  That root-user may read, write and execute it.  That members of the wheel-group is allwoed to execute it, but not to read (eg. copy) it.  And that other users may neither read, write nor execute it.  (The command `su` exists on Linux also, but here all users may execute it - it still runs as the root-user though.)

Other programs may also run as some system-user (and group) - for example the `apache`web-server is often run as the www-data-user (and www-data-group).  This way it can't do too much damage if compromised, due to lack of permissions where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 5):

Your second point is correct, members of the group `root` can read the file but cannot write or execute it.

Your first point is incorrect - even the `root` user cannot execute this file. `root` can easily change the permissions to make it executable, but cannot actually execute it until that step is taken.

An important caveat to note is that with shell scripts or other plain-text scripts, they can be "sourced" for execution without the executable bit being set. In this example, if the contents of the `1.txt` file are actually a bash script, even with the 0650 permissions, you would be able to run `bash 1.txt` and have the commands inside the file executed, effectively running the script and seeming to get around the execution permission bit.

The caveat can be seen here:

```
# ./myecho
Hi there!
# chmod -x myecho
# ./myecho
-bash: ./myecho: Permission denied
# sh myecho
Hi there!
```

Comment: *"Your first point is incorrect - even the root user cannot execute this file"* This is not true, I removed the `x` permission (in the user permissions) of a program owned by `root` and I executed it as `root` and it executed successfully.

Comment: Steve - see the edit. You cannot execute files that are marked non-executable, even as root. You can source them in a shell, but you cannot execute them.

Comment: I didn't execute a shell script, I executed a C program. I executed it in the terminal (that has `bash` on the other end) like this: `./myProgram`, and I double clicked on it in `Nautilus` (`Nautilus` was running as `root`), in both cases it was executed successfully.

Comment: You're doing something you don't realize, or you're not doing something you think you are. Perhaps you only removed the user-execute bit, not all execute bits.

Comment: You are right, the group `x` bit was still on. But this is weird, shouldn't the C program not get executed if the user `x` bit is not set, and the the group `x` bit should not matter at all?